# How to use the registered shell overlay icon from TortoiseSVN in my c# app

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn, hook, overlay, dropbox

tortoiseSVN and Dropbox come up with a hook that display an overlay icons on files. 
when a file status changed, the hook handle this change and change the overlay icon.

this hook is in ShellOverlayIcon in the registry and it used like the windows shortcut arrow icon when shortcut is created.

Can i use those hook handler in my c# app ?
Can i change a flag of file to marked as SVNchange flag so TortoiseSvn icon handler will change automatically the icon of the file ? 
if yes can you provide an example (in c#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After regarding some solution ive found "TortoiseOverlays" projects that used in TortoiseSvn project 
here is my another question to resolve the usage of this hooks  [How to use TortoiseOverlays with my own handler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9465602/1205557)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use those existing hooks, but [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects) is a good article which explains how to make your own hook.

EDIT: Sorry the article uses C++.

Comment: unfortunately i'm trying to evite to create a new hooks
**1.** windows shell is limited by maximum numbers of hooks (like 16)
**2.** tortoise has the same hooks and icon that i need, and has separate installation for those overlay, so i don't need to install all tortoise application.

Comment: [totoisesvn overlays usage documentation](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/svn/tortoisesvn/TortoiseOverlays/version-1.0.5/Documentation.txt) (user : guest)
explain how to use those hooks