# How to use TortoiseOverlays with my own handler

Tags: c++, tortoisesvn, hook, overlay, windows-shell

tortoiseSVN has a shell hook that add overlay icons on files. 
They create a separate open source project to use it in their commons projects (tortoiseSvn,tortoiseGit,etc)

i've download the [installer .msi from google code](http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/TortoiseOverlays/version-1.1.3/bin/) that install the hooker handler
i've got my own version of "IShellIconOverlayIdentifier::IsMemberOf" that use for the handlers
how i grab all together ?

[Here is the only doc i found](http://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/TortoiseOverlays/version-1.1.3/Documentation.txt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note that the TortoiseOverlays handler does not reduce the work you have to do: you have to implement your own overlay handler and get it to work fully. Only then can you make use of the TortoiseOverlays handler if you still want to:

The purpose of the TortoiseOverlays handler is to share the handler slots the windows shell has (limited to 15). It's not to help you implement overlay handlers.

Once you have your own handler working, you can simply change the registry keys where you register your own handler. After that, TortoiseOverlays will be loading your overlay handler.